# Como omitir la primera fila de un archivo xlsx

Tags: php, simplexlsx

Estoy usando SimpleXLSX para importar archivos de excel a mi base de datos, pero no quiero que la primera línea se agregue, intente usar el continue pero lo que hace es insertarme toda la data de la tabla dos veces

Aquí les dejo el código

```
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {

 require_once __DIR__ . '/simplexlsx.class.php';

 if ( $xlsx = SimpleXLSX::parse( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] ) ) {
  $stmt = $conn->prepare( "INSERT INTO paises (item, codigo_sap, descripcion, und, menor_precio, peso, volumen, provmenor, paisprov, nproceso, emprescon, econtra, fecha) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
  $stmt->bindParam( 1, $item);
  $stmt->bindParam( 2, $codsap);
  $stmt->bindParam( 3, $desc);
  $stmt->bindParam( 4, $und);
  $stmt->bindParam( 5, $menor);
  $stmt->bindParam( 6, $peso);
  $stmt->bindParam( 7, $volumen);
  $stmt->bindParam( 8, $provme);
  $stmt->bindParam( 9, $provpis);
  $stmt->bindParam( 10, $proceso);
  $stmt->bindParam( 11, $econcur);
  $stmt->bindParam( 12, $econtr);
  $stmt->bindParam( 13, $fecha);
    foreach ( $xlsx->rows() as $fields ) {
        if($fields== 1){ $fields++; continue; }
        $item = $fields[0];
        $codsap = $fields[1];
        $desc = $fields[2];
        $und = $fields[3];
        $menor = $fields[4];
        $peso = $fields[5];
        $volumen = $fields[6];
        $provme = $fields[7];
        $provpis = $fields[8];
        $proceso = $fields[9];
        $econcur = $fields[10];
        $econtr = $fields[11];
        $fecha = $fields[12];
        $stmt->execute();

    }

} else {
    echo SimpleXLSX::parse_error();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que lo mas eficiente seria simplemente desechar la primera fila del array devuelto por el metodo rows, de esta forma evitas que en cada ciclo se ejecute un if que no aporta nada, es decir:

```
// Obtienes el array
$filas = $xlsx->rows();
// eliminas el indice 0 (la primera fila)
unset($filas[0]);
// recorres el array
foreach ( $fila as $fields ) {
    $item = $fields[0];
    $codsap = $fields[1];
    $desc = $fields[2];
    $und = $fields[3];
    $menor = $fields[4];
    $peso = $fields[5];
    $volumen = $fields[6];
    $provme = $fields[7];
    $provpis = $fields[8];
    $proceso = $fields[9];
    $econcur = $fields[10];
    $econtr = $fields[11];
    $fecha = $fields[12];
    $stmt->execute();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Intentalo asi:

```
foreach ( $xlsx->rows() as $i => $fields ) {
    if($i== 0){ continue; }
    $item = $fields[0];
    $codsap = $fields[1];
    $desc = $fields[2];
    $und = $fields[3];
    $menor = $fields[4];
    $peso = $fields[5];
    $volumen = $fields[6];
    $provme = $fields[7];
    $provpis = $fields[8];
    $proceso = $fields[9];
    $econcur = $fields[10];
    $econtr = $fields[11];
    $fecha = $fields[12];
    $stmt->execute();

}
```

Comment: Asi me esta quitando la primera linea pero sigue insertando dos veces la tabla

Answer (score 0):

Incluye el registro de los datos dentro del if y salta el $i == 0

```
foreach ( $xlsx->rows() as $i => $fields ) {
    if($i> 0){
    $item = $fields[0];
    $codsap = $fields[1];
    $desc = $fields[2];
    $und = $fields[3];
    $menor = $fields[4];
    $peso = $fields[5];
    $volumen = $fields[6];
    $provme = $fields[7];
    $provpis = $fields[8];
    $proceso = $fields[9];
    $econcur = $fields[10];
    $econtr = $fields[11];
    $fecha = $fields[12];
    $stmt->execute();
   }
}
```

Prueba esto